# C++ OnnxRuntime_GPU: Session Run throws an access violation exception

Tags: c++, python-3.x, optimization, onnxruntime

I am writing a .dll extension that takes in NumPy images from Python and performs inference on them. The inference works fine on a CPU session.

I then used the CUDA provider in hopes of getting a speedup, using the default settings.

```
Ort::Session OnnxRuntime::CreateSession(string onnx_path) {
    // Don't declare raw pointers in the headers and try to return a reference here.
    // ORT will throw an access violation.

    Ort::Env env;
    Ort::SessionOptions session_options;
    OrtCUDAProviderOptions cuda_options;
    cuda_options.device_id = 0;
    cuda_options.cudnn_conv_algo_search = OrtCudnnConvAlgoSearchExhaustive;
    cuda_options.gpu_mem_limit = static_cast<int>(SIZE_MAX * 1024 * 1024);
    cuda_options.arena_extend_strategy = 1;
    cuda_options.do_copy_in_default_stream = 1;
    cuda_options.has_user_compute_stream = 1;
    cuda_options.default_memory_arena_cfg = nullptr;
    session_options.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cuda_options);

    session_options.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(
        GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);

    wstring widestr = std::wstring(onnx_path.begin(), onnx_path.end());
    const wchar_t* onnx_path_widecstr = widestr.c_str();
    Ort::Session _session = Ort::Session(env, onnx_path_widecstr, session_options);
    return _session;
    }
```

I got a violation access exception when trying to run the session.

```
Windows fatal exception: access violation

    Thread 0x000058e0 (most recent call first):
      File "C:\Users\Deployment\.conda\envs\sw_2021\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 78 in _worker
      File "C:\Users\Deployment\.conda\envs\sw_2021\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
      File "C:\Users\Deployment\.conda\envs\sw_2021\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
      File "C:\Users\Deployment\.conda\envs\sw_2021\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
```

System information

```
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Windows 10
ONNX Runtime installed from (source or binary): binary (Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.GPU from the NuGet installer)
ONNX Runtime version: 1.10.0
Python version: 3.7.11
Visual Studio version (if applicable): VS 2019
GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): MSVC Version 19.16.27043 for x86
CUDA/cuDNN version: CUDA10.2/CUDNN7.6.5
GPU model and memory: GeForce RTX2080 Ti
```

The code would not run without the model, data and suitable infrastructure (which I cannot share). However, the main inference code is shown below.

```
py::dict run(string onnx_path, py::dict images, py::list image_stats, py::list np_labels) {
    DataLoader dataloader = DataLoader(images, image_stats, np_labels);
    
    std::vector<string> labels = dataloader.GetLabels();
    unordered_map<int, cv::Mat> frames = dataloader.GetImages();

    OnnxRuntime onnx = OnnxRuntime();
    Ort::Session session = onnx.CreateSession(onnx_path);

    //as of 4th Feb 2022 Onnx only supports allocation on the CPU
    Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu( 
        OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator, OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);

    //onnx.SessionInfo(&session);
    Ort::TypeInfo inputTypeInfo = session.GetInputTypeInfo(0);
    auto inputTensorInfo = inputTypeInfo.GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo();
    Ort::TypeInfo outputTypeInfo = session.GetOutputTypeInfo(0);
    auto outputTensorInfo = outputTypeInfo.GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo();

    std::vector<int64_t> inputDims = inputTensorInfo.GetShape();
    std::vector<int64_t> outputDims = outputTensorInfo.GetShape();
    size_t inputTensorSize = vectorProduct(inputDims);
    size_t outputTensorSize = vectorProduct(outputDims);
    std::vector<float> inputTensorValues(inputTensorSize);
    std::vector<float> outputTensorValues(outputTensorSize);

    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;
    const char* inputName = session.GetInputName(0, allocator);
    const char* outputName = session.GetOutputName(0, allocator);

    py::dict results;

    for (const auto& [id, frame] : frames) {
        std::vector<Ort::Value> inputTensors;
        std::vector<Ort::Value> outputTensors;
        std::vector<const char*> inputNames{ inputName };
        std::vector<const char*> outputNames{ outputName };

        inputTensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            memoryInfo, inputTensorValues.data(), inputTensorSize, inputDims.data(),
            inputDims.size()));
        outputTensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            memoryInfo, outputTensorValues.data(), outputTensorSize,
            outputDims.data(), outputDims.size()));

        inputTensorValues.assign(frame.begin<float>(), frame.end<float>());

        try {
            session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{ nullptr }, inputNames.data(),
                inputTensors.data(), 1, outputNames.data(), outputTensors.data(), 1);
        }
        catch (const std::runtime_error& re) {
            std::cerr << "Runtime error: " << re.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (const std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }

        int predId = 0;
        float activation = 0;
        float maxActivation = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
        float expSum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++)
        {
            activation = outputTensorValues.at(i);
            expSum += std::exp(activation);
            if (activation > maxActivation)
            {
                predId = i;
                maxActivation = activation;
            }
        }

        results[id] = labels.at(predId);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The code is taken from https://github.com/leimao/ONNX-Runtime-Inference/blob/main/src/inference.cpp.

This is the expected behavior.
[image: Expected Behavior]

Actual behavior.
[image: Actual Behavior]

Additional context
A PyTorch ResNet34 model is converted into an ONNX model which is used by the C++ OnnxRuntime. But since the model works fine for the CPU provider, I don't see why it would fail with the CUDA provider.

Comment: Very likely the cuda/cudnn .so files are missing. Copy `libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so` and `libonnxruntime_providers_shared.so` to somewhere in the path and try again